# Display two columns in a numerical order based off 1 column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has a "user" column and a "total" column. what I am trying to do is display both columns  in a two column table but I want the output to be ordered highest total to lowest total. can someone please help me set up this array because everything I have tried has failed.

I've tried this but got nothing

```
<?php

include "includes/config.php";
include "includes/database.php";

$sql = "SELECT user, cur_total FROM curstats";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$user = $cut_attack = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $user[] = $row['user'];
    $cur_total[] = $row['cur_total'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use ORDER by sql clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT user, cur_total FROM curstats order by cur_total desc";
```

DESC - means from highest to lowest

Comment: will this also change the order of the usernames?

Comment: Yes it will, they will be ordered by the total descending.

Comment: ok thanks with the current array I have listed what would I need to do to display the array echo the variables?

Comment: @user3078244 in loop just use `echo $row['user'].' '.$row['cur_total']."<br/>\n";`

Comment: @user3078244, check my answer for printing it in tables.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it into table order is trivial. You could do something like:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Usernames</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['user'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['cur_total'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark solutions as green :)

Comment: ok I got everything working could you possibly tell me how I can create a column on the table that starts at one and will increase by one each array loop?

Comment: For user or total? In my example it will create two columns for both.

Comment: your example worked great but this is a ranking system so I want there to be another column which is easy to add but how can I get a numerical value to increase by 1 each row starting at 1